# Modificar o VIDEO_CODE da API do Youtube sem precisar criar uma nova versao da apk

Tags: api, youtube, api-youtube

Preciso mudar essa String VIDEO_CODE todo dia, pois dentro do app é um bota que leva pra uma transmissao ao vivo, teria como eu fazer isso sem precisar gerar uma nova apk todo dia e gerar uma nova versao no console.

```
private final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyArMe4mfDJZYiA2xumhJp0TwHMaetcOE_g";
private final String VIDEO_CODE = "blzjpuWai_8";

player = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);
    player.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            if (!b){
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(VIDEO_CODE);
                youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            Toast.makeText(aovivo.this, youTubeInitializationResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Teria como [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/306902/edit) a pergunta e colocar o código que já fez?

Comment: ja fiz a alteracao